# finding a local maximum in a 3d array (array of images) in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to implement a blob detector based on LOG, the steps are:

1. creating an array of n levels of LOG filters
2. use each of the filters on the input image to create a 3d array of `h*w*n` where h = height, w = width and n = number of levels.
3. find a local maxima and circle the blob in the original image.

I already created the filters and the 3d array (which is an array of 2d images).
I used padding to make sure I don't have any problems around the borders (which includes creating a constant border for each image and create 2 extra empty images).

Now I'm trying to figure out how to find the local maxima in the array.
I need to compare each pixel to its 26 neighbours (8 in the same picture and the 9 pixels in each of the two adjacent scales)

The brute force way of checking the pixel value directly seems ugly and not very efficient.
Whats the best way to find a local maxima point in python using openCV?

Answer (score 0):

I'd take advantage of the fact that dilations are efficiently implemented in OpenCV. If a point is a local maximum in 3d, then it is also in any 2d slice, therefore:

1. Dilate each image in the array with a 3x3 kernel, keep as candidate maxima the points whose intensity is unchanged.
2. Brute-force test the candidates against their upper and lower slices.